# Pasar variables entre paginas PHP

Tags: php

Me encuentro trabajando con PHP y no encuentro la forma de pasar el valor de una Variable de un archivo PHP a otro.

En mi página filtro1.php tengo un combo. Lo guardo en una variable y compruebo si ha recibido algun valor, si recibe algo, quiero que este valor pase a la página filtro2.php con el valor que seleccioné.

Intenté usar $_SESSION y sí funciona bien siempre y cuando sea en la misma página. Ejemplo: **(filtro1.php)** pero al recogerla en filtro2.php se torna a vacía.

**filtro1.php**

```
    session_start();
$Consulta = "SELECT * FROM articulos";

if(isset($_POST["colores"])){
  $Consulta .= "WHERE color IN ('".implode("','",$_POST["color"])."')";
  echo $Consulta;
}

$_SESSION['Consulta']="$Consulta";
```

Y así retomo el **filtro2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

   echo "Valor: " .$_SESSION['Consulta'];
?>
```

pero sólo me imprime:

Valor:

Por su ayuda Gracias.

Comment: ¿La variable que estás pasando por POST es "color" o "colores"? Lo mismo es que te estás confundiendo y no estás usando el mismo nombre de variable…

Comment: @A.Cedano en todos los manuales de PHP te dice que debes iniciar la sesión, poniendo `session_start()` al principio de todos los archivos php en los que la sesión deba mantenerse. ¿Está mal poner `session_start()` en todos los archivos? Solo se pone en el primero y luego no hace falta? Es que leyendo tu comentario me ha asaltado esa duda.

Comment: `$_SESSION['Consulta']="$Consulta";` no necesitas entrecomillar `$Consulta`.   Cuando haces `echo $Consulta` en el filtro1.php que sale?, cuando menos debe poner `SELECT * FROM articulos`. Si no te hace ese `echo` es que colores no se está enviando.

Comment: Es como tú dices @JoseManuelMorales. Retiro mi comentario.

Comment: Supongo que en filtro1.php se ve el string de la consulta al hacer el echo, ¿cierto? Un pequeño detalle: en la concatenación del WHERE deberías dejar un espacio al comienzo (para que no quede "articulosWHERE". Respecto del problema, lo único que se me ocurre es verificar que la cookie de sesión se esté escribiendo y enviando en el segundo request

Comment: Muchas Gracias a todos por su aportación y ayuda

Comment: He logrado mi objetivo ahora mismo les comparto como es que funciono por si a alguien más le funciona

Answer (score 0):

**filtro1.php**

```
session_start();
$Consulta = "SELECT * FROM articulos";

if(isset($_POST["colores"])){
  $Consulta .= "WHERE color IN ('".implode("','",$_POST["color"])."')";
  echo $Consulta;
}

$_SESSION['Consulta']="$Consulta";
```

y en el mismo archivo imprimí las linea que obtendría después de seleccionar mis checkbox (solo para verificar)

```
$mon = $_SESSION['Consulta'];
echo $mon;
```

En **filtro1.php** mande el resultado al otro archivo (filtro2.php) con href

```
 <a href="filtro2.php?variable=<?php echo $mon;?>">
```

Y en **filtro2.php** la recupere con esta sencilla linea

```
    $consulta = $_GET['variable'];
```

No se si sea la forma correcta, así que acepto cambios y sugerencias, Muchas Gracias a todos chicos por su aporte.